# Tensorflow Custom Estimator: How to implement a `input_fn` function that returns a list of labels, and a list of features ?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert my Tensorflow graph to use a custom tensorflow estimator, but I am getting stuck defining the function for `input_fn` ; I am currently getting an error.

This is the function I use to generate my input data and labels

```
data_index = 0 
epoch_index = 0 
recEpoch_indexA = 0 #Used to help keep store of the total number of epoches with the models

def generate_batch(batch_size, inputCount): 
    global data_index, epoch_index

    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, inputCount), dtype=np.int32) 
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)

    n=0
    while n < batch_size:
      if len(    set(my_data[data_index, 1])   ) >= inputCount:
        labels[n,0] = my_data[data_index, 0]
        batch[n] = random.sample( set(my_data[data_index, 1]),  inputCount)
        n = n+1
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data) #may have to do something like len my_data[:]
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)
      else:
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data)
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)

    return batch, labels
```

This is where I define my Estimator and attempt to do training

```
#Define the estimator
word2vecEstimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=my_model,
        params={
            'batch_size': 1024,
            'embedding_size': 50,
            'num_inputs': 5,
            'num_sampled':128
        })

batch_size = 16
num_inputs = 3

#Train with Estimator
word2vecEstimator.train(
    input_fn=generate_batch(batch_size, num_inputs),
    steps=10)
```

This is the error message that I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)
   1118                                        skip_bound_arg=False,
-> 1119                                        sigcls=Signature)
   1120     except Exception as ex:

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in _signature_from_callable(obj, follow_wrapper_chains, skip_bound_arg, sigcls)
   2185     if not callable(obj):
-> 2186         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
   2187 

TypeError: (array([[1851833,  670357,  343012],
       [ 993526,  431296,  935528],
       [ 938067, 1155719, 2277388],
       [ 534965, 1125669, 1665716],
       [1412657, 2152211, 1176177],
       [ 268114, 2097642, 2707258],
       [1280762, 1516464,  453615],
       [2545980, 2302607, 2421182],
       [1706260, 2735027,  292652],
       [1802025, 2949676,  653015],
       [ 854228, 2626773,  225486],
       [1747135, 1608478, 2503487],
       [1326661,  272883, 2089444],
       [3082922, 1359481,  621031],
       [2636832, 1842777, 1979638],
       [2512269, 1617986,  389356]], dtype=int32), array([[1175598],
       [2528125],
       [1870906],
       [ 643521],
       [2349752],
       [ 754986],
       [2277570],
       [2121120],
       [2384306],
       [1881398],
       [3046987],
       [2505729],
       [2908573],
       [2438025],
       [ 441422],
       [2355625]], dtype=int32)) is not a callable object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7acc939af001> in <module>()
      5 word2vecEstimator.train(
      6     input_fn=generate_batch(batch_size, num_inputs),
----> 7     steps=10)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    352 
    353       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 354       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    355       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    356       return self

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1205       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1206     else:
-> 1207       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1208 
   1209   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1232       features, labels, input_hooks = (
   1233           self._get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(
-> 1234               input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
   1235       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1236       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(self, input_fn, mode)
   1073     """Extracts the `features` and labels from return values of `input_fn`."""
   1074     return estimator_util.parse_input_fn_result(
-> 1075         self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
   1076 
   1077   def _extract_batch_length(self, preds_evaluated):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_input_fn(self, input_fn, mode)
   1151       ValueError: if `input_fn` takes invalid arguments.
   1152     """
-> 1153     input_fn_args = function_utils.fn_args(input_fn)
   1154     kwargs = {}
   1155     if 'mode' in input_fn_args:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/function_utils.py in fn_args(fn)
     54     if _is_callable_object(fn):
     55       fn = fn.__call__
---> 56     args = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(fn).args
     57     if _is_bounded_method(fn):
     58       args.remove('self')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_inspect.py in getfullargspec(obj)
    214   return next((d.decorator_argspec
    215                for d in decorators
--> 216                if d.decorator_argspec is not None), _getfullargspec(target))
    217 
    218 

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)
   1123         # else. So to be fully backwards compatible, we catch all
   1124         # possible exceptions here, and reraise a TypeError.
-> 1125         raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
   1126 
   1127     args = []

TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Here is a link to the Google Colab notebook for people to run on their own. For anyone looking to execute this, this will download a data file that is ~500 mbs.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LjIz04xhRi5Fsw_Q3IzoG_5KkkXI3WFE

And here is the full code, from the notebook.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import zipfile
import shutil
from collections import namedtuple

import os
import pprint

import tensorflow as tf

import pandas as pd
import pickle
from numpy import genfromtxt

!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from google.colab import files
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

vocabulary_size = 3096637 #updated 10-25-18 3096636

import gc

dl_id = '19yha9Scxq4zOdfPcw5s6L2lkYQWenApC' #updated 10-22-18

myDownload = drive.CreateFile({'id': dl_id})
myDownload.GetContentFile('Data.npy')
my_data = np.load('Data.npy')
#os.remove('Data.npy')
np.random.shuffle(my_data)
print(my_data[0:15])

data_index = 0 
epoch_index = 0 
recEpoch_indexA = 0 #Used to help keep store of the total number of epoches with the models

def generate_batch(batch_size, inputCount): 
    global data_index, epoch_index

    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, inputCount), dtype=np.int32) 
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)

    n=0
    while n < batch_size:
      if len(    set(my_data[data_index, 1])   ) >= inputCount:
        labels[n,0] = my_data[data_index, 0]
        batch[n] = random.sample( set(my_data[data_index, 1]),  inputCount)
        n = n+1
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data) #may have to do something like len my_data[:]
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)
      else:
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data)
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)

    return batch, labels     

def my_model( features, labels, mode, params):

#     train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, num_inputs ])
#     train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

    train_dataset = features
    train_labels = labels

    batch_sizeE=params["batch_size"]
    embedding_sizeE=params["embedding_size"]
    num_inputsE=params["num_inputs"]
    num_sampledE=params["num_sampled"]

    epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0) #to store epoch count to total # of epochs are known
    update_epoch = tf.assign(epochCount, epochCount + 1)

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_sizeE], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_sizeE],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_sizeE), dtype=tf.float32 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float32),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_sizeE*num_inputs, embedding_sizeE] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds, 
                                   sampled_values=tf.nn.uniform_candidate_sampler(true_classes=tf.cast(train_labels, tf.int64), num_sampled=num_sampled, num_true=1, unique=True, range_max=vocabulary_size, seed=None),
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)) 

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

#Define the estimator
word2vecEstimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=my_model,
        params={
            'batch_size': 1024,
            'embedding_size': 50,
            'num_inputs': 5,
            'num_sampled':128
        })

batch_size = 16
num_inputs = 3

#Train with Estimator
word2vecEstimator.train(
    input_fn=generate_batch(batch_size, num_inputs),
    steps=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here

[Tensorflow error : unsupported callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140164/tensorflow-error-unsupported-callable?rq=1)

> train method accepts the input function, so it should be input_fn, not input_fn().

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of correcting the function, cuz it can never be implemented using Tensorflow. The input_fn() function must return Tensors, not numpy arrays, cuz the input_fn() is a function constructing the graph, and it maybe is just called once when building the graph. In this context, the numpy array is just a constant value. It may seem to be weird, But it's the truth. You need to understand the mechanism of Tensorflow: the STATIC COMPUTE GRAPH!